# Problem debugging shell extension in Vista (IShellFolder)

Tags: windows, shell-extensions

I have created a Windows Shell Extension using ATL (Visual Studio 2008). It has the following modules and each module is a separate ATL Simple Object with its own .rgs file for registration:-

1. IShellFolder/IShellView -> For a virtual drive in windows explorer
2. IContextMenu/IShellExtInit -> For a popup menu files and folders
3. IShellIconOverlayIdentifier - To display overlay icons on files and folders
4. IShellPropSheetExt/IShellExtInit -> For a custom property page in File & Folder's properties

The above work fine in WinXP and I am able to debug this shell extension in WinXP. But a soon as I switch to Vista, I only get method calls for (2) and (4). The drive gets created in Windows Explorer but the underlying methods are not called when I click it.
Although when I right click I get called for (2) and when I select "Properties" for a file or folder I get into the code for (4).

Is there some interface that I am missing for (1) and (3) on Vista. I could not find full and detailed documentation on writing Shell Extensions for Vista on MSDN. I had already gone through the CodeProject articles on shell extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because of a Xml SMART Pointer usage. It was has problems when Release() was called on it.

Check this link
[Internet Explorer crashes when MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr -> Release() is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641896/internet-explorer-crashes-when-msxml2ixmldomdocumentptr-release-is-called)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your extensions are handling the initialization properly, otherwise the verclsid.exe won't let your extension getting loaded.
verclsid.exe first loads the shell extensions and does a quick check on them before it sends an 'ok' to the shell indicating that it's safe to load the extension.

See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918165) for some details about verclsid.exe.

Comment: I could not quite get the solution right. I included the verclsid.exe in the firewall's "Allowed" list but when I start debugging, it shows 'explorer.exe': Loaded '...\Debug\ShellExtension.dll'
'explorer.exe': Unloaded '...\Debug\ShellExtension.dll'

And the breakpoint is not hit

Comment: It has nothing to do with a firewall. Unless you do some network stuff in your dll init function (which you *never* should do).
the "(un)loaded"  lines in the debug window don't help here. You can check in your init functions in which process the dll is loaded.

Comment: I apologise for the late reply, I was away.
By Init function, do you mean dllmain()? In there, I am not doing much

::CoInitialize(NULL);
if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
{
_AtlModule.Init();
::DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hInstance);
}
hInstance;
return _AtlModule.DllMain(dwReason, lpReserved);

Comment: I doubt if IShellFolder and IPersistFolder are the only interfaces that needs to implemented in Vista. There might be another *required* interface

Comment: Not just dllmain - verclsid also does some testing on QueryInterface() and depending on what extension it is also on some other interfaces.

And no: Vista does not require any interface to be implemented that wasn't on XP.

Comment: Where can I find this QueryInterface() initialization?

Comment: QueryInterface is part of the IUnknown interface

Comment: ya but I could not find the implementation.