# Internet Explorer crashes when MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr -> Release() is called

Tags: shell, atl

I am creating a shell extension in C++ (ATL 9) using Visual Studio 2008. The Shell Extension creates a global MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr object m_XmlDoc in the module class. This m_XmlDoc is then used in the extension by all classes to read xml document.

The problem that I am facing is with Internet explorer. When the Shell Extension is active and I open/close internet explorer, I get a debug dialog and IE crashes. The error message says "Unhandled exception at 0x6aac30f1 in iexplore.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x03050970."
When I click "break" on the message window, It takes me to the "Release" method of COM Smart Pointer and the error seems to be on 
m_pInterface->Release();

This call was made from Module's destructor and also the value of m_pInterface is not NULL. I think maybe internet explorer is using the XML DOM and the call to Release creates some problem in it.

```
MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr m_XmlDoc;

In _AtlModule.Init() method
    ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    m_XmlDoc.CreateInstance(MSXML2::CLSID_DOMDocument40);
```

dllMain code:

```
extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        _AtlModule.Init();  
        CreateImageLists();
        ::DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hInstance);
    }

    hInstance;
    return _AtlModule.DllMain(dwReason, lpReserved); 
}
```

Comment: On a first glance this looks like a double-free. Can you share some more source?

Comment: This comment window only allows 300 chars, I dont know how I can put more source in here?

Comment: Should I edit the original post?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was because of the COM Smart Pointer used for XmlDomDocument. I changed it to a normal pointer and it is working fine even in Vista.

This problem has a different behaviour in XP and Vista. In XP, I was getting an unhandled exception when I closed Internet Explorer. In Vista, I was not able to browse the virtual drive.

Comment: Sorry, You have not "fixed" anything at all by not releasing the reference to the object you created.

Comment: I know that is not a real fix to this problem but atleast I found the problem that was causing the crash. There may be other ways to use the Smart COM pointer that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

the use of DisableThreadLibraryCalls is discouraged, you seen it?

Comment: Why is it discouraged? The problem seems to be with the COM Smart Pointer for XmlDomDocument. I changed from Smart Pointer to a normal one and the problem is gone.

Comment: So far as I'm aware the only warning against DisableThreadLibraryCalls is this one: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555563

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two problems with your code as posted:

1. You're calling CoInitialize in DllMain.
2. You're creating a COM object in DllMain.
3. It wouldn't surprise me if you're doing something in CreateImageLists() which you also shouldn't be doing in DllMain.

Also, the reason that your crash was "fixed" by not using the smart pointer is because now you're not actually releasing the object anymore.  Your code is broken, and not releasing the reference isn't a valid way to fix anything.

I would suggest that you read, and then re-read, the documentation for [DllMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583.aspx) paying particular attention to the things you should never do within your implementation of the function.  As you'll see right up front:

> **Warning**  There are serious limits on what you can do in a DLL entry point. To provide more complex initialization, create an initialization routine for the DLL. You can require applications to call the initialization routine before calling any other routines in the DLL.

I suspect once you read it, and fix your code to create the COM object at a valid time, and release it at a valid time, your shell extension will stop crashing.